# Connect device to internet while debugging

Tags: android, debugging

I have developed an app and now I have to check it in my mobile. I don't have any internet facility in my phone. So I just want to know whether there is a way that I could make use of to connect my mobile to internet in the debugging mode connected to my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wireless connection from you PC and then connect you phone to it.